# How to solve the problem of high CPU load?

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

After installing Macubuntu pack processor became heavily loaded, I replaced Ubuntu 64-bit with Xubuntu 64-bit, but the processor is still heavily loaded when performing simple actions (open file manager, install soft). It loaded almost 100 or 100 percent.
I have also Windows on it, and there is too such problem.

2Gb RAM, Processor AMD Dual-Core c60

Comment: What's your system configuration ? ie. RAM and Processor

Comment: It might mean that ubuntu isn't using your GPU and does software rendering instead. Try seeing if you can install drivers for your GPU

Comment: De[pends on what is causing the cpu load. Run top in a terminal and check. @TatakaiWasumi identified the most common problem which can be solved bu using an alternate (non-gnome) interface such as K/X/lubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "top" command to find the program that is causing problem. you can either kill the program if its not necessary or use the package "cpulimit" to limit its cpu usage. To install cpulimit:

apt-get install cpulimit

Check the manpage of cpulimit to get the idea of using it.

****Caution: the cpu limited program will respond slowly as expected so it totally depends on upon what process you are using it.